# Ordering mysql result by number of regexp matches

Tags: mysql, regex

I've the following query. It selects all posts where the title contains the words green, blue or red.

> SELECT id, title FROM post WHERE title REGEXP '(green|blue|red)'

I would like to sort the results in such a way that the title with the most matches (all three words) and thus the most relevant one, is listed first. Is this possible in this scenario and if so, how I would go on about it?

Thanks

Comment: `SELECT id,title FROM post ORDER BY FIELD(color,'green','blue','red')`

Answer (score 0):

You must split the regex. Either to different conditions or different queries:

```
SELECT COUNT(results.username) as count, results.* FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `title` LIKE "%blue%"
    UNION SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `title` LIKE "%red%"
    UNION SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE `title` LIKE "%green%"
) as results GROUP BY results.title ORDER BY count DESC;
```

Note: I used `LIKE` instead of `REGEXP`, becouse when you split the condition you wont need it anymore according to your example. `LIKE` is a bit faster then regex, but if your pattern is more complex, then you can always replace it back.

Comment: As mentioned in [Alma Do's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20467825/1697320), you're better off with FULLTEXT.